# Convert .dll format to .exe format?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, exe

I have c++ project developed in Visual studio, when i was build my project got .dll file and some other files are existed in some directory. So my question is, Any ways are there for convert my existed .dll file to .exe file ???

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want simply to get *.exe instead of *.dll after build (note, that you need `main` function - or it equivalent in non-C language) then:

1. open solution
2. *right-click* on project you want to compile into exe -> **Properties**
3. **Configuration Properties** -> **General**
4. In **Project Defaults** change **Configuration Type** to **Application(.exe)**

Comment: `Configuration Properties` don't see it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just simply convert any .dll file to program executable .exe. This is more a work for a programmer, not a simple conversion any user can make with some kind of utility.